# Importing images into Kubernetes with ctr will remove others

Tags: kubernetes, ctr

I'm trying to import @80 images into an offline Kubernetes environment.
The problem is that when the import is finished I'll have @30 images only so not all images are imported

What I observed is that when importing some images, those images will remove others.
How can I investigate/fix that?

How I created the images is with:

```
docker save <image> > something{1}.tar
docker save <image> > something{2}.tar
...
```

Command to import images is:

```
ctr image import something{...}.tar --platform linux/amd64
```

More or less this is what I'm doing

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

This is a sign of not enough space and then the images are deleted automatically.

In my case I had to check the containerd.log and had `ImageDelete` events:
`/var/lib/rancher/k3s/agent/containerd/containerd.log`

`time="2024-01-26T15:42:18.884230214+01:00" level=info msg="ImageDelete event name:\"sha256:8b215fdc9a79f9c49df88d7806dc70b063cfaa6dc50015698d...\""`